# Executar arquivos Python, usando o python

Tags: python

Existe alguma forma de executar um arquivo x em Python usando um arquivo y em Python, por meio de códigos Python?

Answer (score 0):

sim, isso é inerente em linguagens de programação.

A forma "certa" é importar o arquivo x.py como um **módulo**.

veja:

*x.py*

```
print('olá do modulo X')

def main():
    print('olá da função principal "x.main()"')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

*y.py*

```
import x
# >>> 'olá do modulo X
x.main()
# >>> olá da função principal "x.main()"
```

Alternativamente é possível rodar arquivos .py como um processo separado, usando o o interpretador Python, para isso, use o **modulo** `subprocess`:

*y.py*

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run("python x.py", shell=True)
# >>> olá do modulo X
# >>> olá da função principal "x.main()"
```

para ver mais:

https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/modules.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Obrigado!!! Deu certo